# Remover classe de uma div com um ID especifico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tem como remover uma classe de uma div com um `ID` especifico?

Essa `div` é inserida dinamicamente através do `append`, e cada uma recebe seu `ID`. Só que tem momentos que preciso remover somente UMA `div` que foi inserida com `append`, como elas tem a mesma classe mas não o mesmo `ID`, tem como fazer algo do tipo?

Por exemplo:

```
$('.remove > id = 6').remove();
```

é possível?

Comment: `$("#6").remove()` não resolve? Como você quer remover? Ao clicar num botão?

Comment: `$("[id='6']").remove()` Já ia escrever isso... não entendi direto outra opção

Comment: Não... vou remover dinamicamente, junto com o append.

Comment: Eu recebo o id assim: results.rows.item(i).id; como poderia fazer para remover assim? $(results.rows.item(i).id).remove()?

Comment: Sem saber o que é `results.rows` não tem como te ajudar.

Comment: É o resultado da minha consulta no banco de dados. results.rows.item(i).id me retorna os id. Logo, guardo numa variável. var id = results.rows.item(i).id;

Comment: Já que você tem o identificador salvo em um variável, concatene o `#` com o identificador e mande remover, tente assim: `$('#' + id).remove();`

Comment: @PedroPaulo com a classe remove ficaria algo assim?  $('.remove> #' + id).remove();

Comment: Ficaria sim, porém como o @fernandosavio comentou, não há necessidade de especificar a classe, pois o identificador é único (pelo menos deveria ser) e já funciona para encontrar o elemento.

Comment: Ele quer remover apenas o id que contiver a classe remove, portanto terá que fazer um each na classe remove e remover os ids dentro do loop

Answer (score 0):

Concatene a classe o id no seletor:

```
$('.remove#6').remove();
```

Que significa que deve remover todo elemento que tenha a classe "remove" e o id "6";

Lembrando que o id deve ser único entre todos os elementos de sua página, sendo assim você poderia utilizar apenas:

```
 $('#6').remove();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: Em javascript para remover uma classe de um elemento no ID
`var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
demo.classList.remove("classe-para-remover");`
caso também desejar adicionar e remover a classe por um evento pode usar o toggle
`demo.classList.toggle("class-manipulada");`